# What organization creates or is the custodian of HTML meta tags?

Tags: html, meta

Whom or what organization creates html meta tags such ?

I tried researching on Google and posting a similar question on Quora.

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>All our teak furniture is water proof.</title>
      <meta name="keywords" content="teak, wood, furniture, waterproof">

     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why does this merit a -1?

Answer (score 0):

World Wide Web Consortium now manages it (https://www.w3.org). The W3C is made up of many people from different companies and organizations, including Google, Mozilla, and Microsoft (see https://www.w3.org/Consortium/facts.html).